# IOS: random paging scrollview

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, scroll

I have this code for a scrollView (with paging enabled)

```
- (IBAction) random{
CGRect frame = scrollView.frame;
frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * (arc4random() % (numberOfPage - 1));
frame.origin.y = 0;
[scrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];}
```

It make a random paging scroll and it's ok, but it is very slow. Can I have a fast scrolling as a slot machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you could get it to look like slot machine (you'd probably need some motion blur to get that kind of effect), but you could try putting your `scrollRectToVisible:` in an animation block to change the duration of the animation:

```
- (IBAction) random 
{
    CGRect frame = scrollView.frame;
    frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * (arc4random() % (numberOfPage - 1));
    frame.origin.y = 0;

    [UIView animateWithDuration: <your duration>
                     animations:^(void) {
                         [scrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated: NO];
                     }];
}
```

Don't forget the `animated:NO`, otherwise it'll override your duration

Comment: it's ok, it work fine but my scroll view has a infinite paging loop, then, when I start random can I see a random scrolling with more pages? because this scroll random scroll few pages.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure I really understand what you're asking!